# How to load multiple pages from a REST API in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, simplexml

Below is a simple example of code to fetch results from a REST XML API.

This is just a small portion I have extracted from my real PHP class for this question.

in the API URL which returns an XML document, I am curious about how I could fetch all the results from 1 page and then move on to fetch from the next page.

`$this->api_page` sets the page that the API returns data from.

Looking at the basic code below using `SimpleXMLElement` how could I for example return the data from 10 pages or all pages in the API starting at a page number, loading the results for that page and then fetching the next page an moving on.

Right now I am doing it with JavaScript and PHP by passing a `Page number` in the URL to my script using `$_GET['page']` the problem with this is it requires a user to load the page and it's kind of sloppy.

My real API script will be ran from a Cron job on the server, so with that in mind, how could I fetch all pages?

I ask this question based on this example code below but also because it is a task that I often have to do on other projects and I don't know a good way of doing this?

```
<?php

$this->api_url = 'http://api.rescuegroups.org/rest/?key=' .$this->api_key.
'&type=animals&limit=' .$this->api_limit.
'&startPage='. $this->api_page;

$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($this->api_url, NULL, TRUE); 

foreach($xmlObj->pet as $pet){

    echo $pet->animalID;
    echo $pet->orgID;
    echo $pet->status;

    // more fields from the  Pet object that is returned from the API call

    // Save results to my own Database

}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just loop through pages counting from api_page ... and then either get the "max-page" from the XML or keep going until you get a 404?

Comment: yeah I have the same feeling as Bjørne Malmanger. What's the real problem for all of this?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, mainly because just loading all the pages 1 at a time now takes about 5 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the assumption that you run on a pretty stable environment you could loop through the pages like this:

```
<?php
$this->base_url = 'http://api.rescuegroups.org/rest/?key=' .$this->api_key.
'&type=animals&limit=' .$this->api_limit.
'&startPage=';
$start_page = $this->api_page;
$end_page = 10; //If you have a value for max pages.
// sometimes you might get the number of pages from the first returned XML and then you could update the $end_page inside the loop.

for ($counter = $start_page; $counter <= $end_page; $counter++) {
    try {
        $xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($this->base_url . $counter, NULL, TRUE); 

        foreach($xmlObj->pet as $pet){

            echo $pet->animalID;
            echo $pet->orgID;
            echo $pet->status;

            // more fields from the  Pet object that is returned from the API call

            // Save results to my own Database

        }


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong, possibly no more pages?
        // Please Note! You wil also get an Exception if there is an error in the XML
        // If so you should do some extra error handling
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Right now to get all the results from all the pages takes like 5 hours because there are soo many, that's the main reason I am not sure this would work

Comment: If you run it as a cron job it should work (there shouldn't be browser timeout issue). It is also possible to divide it into page groups. i.e. 1-20, 21-40, 41 - MAX

Comment: If runtime is an issue. You should start several cron jobs in parallel to have more "threads". Be warned, that if this is not your site, you could get IP banned.